# Enviar datos de formulario a MySQL y evitar mensaje de reenvío al refrescar la página

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Este es mi código para hacer un update, estoy tomando los datos de la base de datos para rellenar los inputs pero al momento en que doy click en actualizar, efectivamente manda los datos pero cuando doy al boton de refrescar del navegador intenta mandar de nuevo los datos... ¿cómo evito esto sin usar jquery o java?

```
<?php 

include "index.php";

require 'functions.php';


require_once "views/extras/header-index.php";
require_once "views/extras/header-in.php";


    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $id = limpiarDatos($_POST['id']);
        $nombre = limpiarDatos($_POST['nombre']);
        $apellidos = limpiarDatos($_POST['apellidos']);
        $profesion = limpiarDatos($_POST['profesion']);
        $ciudad = limpiarDatos($_POST['ciudad']);
        $puesto = limpiarDatos($_POST['puesto']);
        $empresa = limpiarDatos($_POST['empresa']);
        $responsabilidades = limpiarDatos($_POST['responsabilidades']);
        $habilidades = limpiarDatos($_POST['habilidades']);
        $carrera = limpiarDatos($_POST['carrera']);
        $universidad = limpiarDatos($_POST['universidad']);
        $extra = limpiarDatos($_POST['extra']);
        $thumb_guardada = $_POST['thumb-guardada'];
        $thumb = $_FILES['thumb'];

        if (empty($thumb['name'])) {
            $thumb = $thumb_guardada;
        } else {
            $archivo_subido = 'images/' . $_FILES['thumb']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['thumb']['tmp_name'], $archivo_subido);
            $thumb = $_FILES['thumb']['name'];
        }

        $errores = '';

        if (empty($nombre) or empty($apellidos)) {
        $errores .= '<li>Por favor rellena todos los datos correctamente</li>';
        } else {
            try {
                $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=empleos', 'root', '');
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            }

            $statement = $conexion->prepare('UPDATE userslog SET nombre = :nombre, apellidos = :apellidos, profesion = :profesion, ciudad = :ciudad, puesto = :puesto, empresa = :empresa, responsabilidades = :responsabilidades, habilidades = :habilidades, carrera = :carrera, universidad = :universidad, extra = :extra, thumb = :thumb WHERE id = :id');

            if ($errores == '') {
                $statement->execute(array(
                    ':id' => $id,
                    ':nombre' => $nombre,
                    ':apellidos' => $apellidos,
                    ':profesion' => $profesion,
                    ':ciudad' => $ciudad,
                    ':puesto' => $puesto,
                    ':empresa' => $empresa,
                    ':responsabilidades' => $responsabilidades,
                    ':habilidades' => $habilidades,
                    ':carrera' => $carrera,
                    ':universidad' => $universidad,
                    ':extra' => $extra,
                    'thumb' => $thumb
            ));

            }
        }
}


require_once "views/perfil.php";
require_once "views/extras/footer.php"; 
?>
```

Comment: Redirige la página una vez se ha insertado el dato. [Post/Redirect/Get](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5690556/1983854)

Comment: Lo intente, pero aun asi persiste

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta con un [mcve] para que podamos ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Como te han comentado los compañeros para evitar que al actualizar la página se reenvien los datos nuevamente lo que debes haces redireccionar después de hacer la actualización a otra página:

Normalmente tenemos este esquema

```
A ---POST---> B
```

Y el esquema que se persigue en tu caso debe ser

```
A ---POST---> B ---GET---> C
```

Ó

```
A ---POST---> B ---GET---> A
```

De forma que B será transparente y en C no estarán los datos POST por lo que no importara que actualice.

Puedes utilizar la siguiente cabecera para redireccionar

```
header('Location: /path/');
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el patrón llamado [Post-Redirect-Get (PRG)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Ejemplo:

```
if ($_POST) {
   // Ejecutar código (CRUD base de datos u otro).

   // Redirigir a esta página.
   header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   exit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Coloca el codigo del programa que hace el trabajo duro en otro archivo y recupera los datos del formulario mediante el método post, y al final del archivo que hace el trabajo trabajo coloca la dirección hacia donde quieres que el usuario llegue.

De esta manera aunque refresque o vuelva atrás no se duplica ni se reenvía la información a tu base de datos.

> Vista usuario ---> POST(archivo que hace el trabajo duro) ---> Lo que quieres que vea luego

Comment: De hecho asi lo tengo, una parte es la vista y otro el codigo, pero si le pongo el header('Locaton: tal.php') me marca error de que en el header ya hay un valor y no se puede cambiar

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos Esto me paso hace poco, estaba llamando una cookie antes de crearla y no me daba error de que no existía la cookie si no de que ya estaba enviando el header desde otro archivo, solo cambie los include de posición y resuelto.

Comment: Cambie el include de lugar como mencionaste pero aun asi persiste el error, hay alguna otra opcion? ya que me marca que el header no se puede modificar ya que se ha mandado anteriormente